# What is the recurrence relations and the asymptotic tight bound for the given pesudo-code?

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory, recurrence

I was given a pseudo-code to find the recurrence relations and the asymptotic tight bound for, and for the life of me i can't figure out how to even try and understand how to confront this.

```
Calc_a(n):
     if n==1:
          return 1
     sum = 0
     for i = 1 to n−1 
          sum = sum + calc_a(i)
return sum
```

First of all, as i said, i was asked to find a recurrence relations formula for this code, and i tried tackling it by following what the code does for a few inputs.
I figured it returns double the amount it returned last time. (except in the case of 1 and 2, where it returns 1 in both).

So i thought to myself - it would probably be something like this: 
`T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + c` 
because the sum it returns is equal to the amount of times the method is called, i added the `c` as a constant to show the amount of "one line works" done each iteration. (i.e the if-else and sum= lines).

The issue is it doesn't fit with what they ask me to do in the second part:
To find a tight asymptotic bound for the relation `Hint:look both at T(n) and at T(n + 1) at the same time`

But with the relation i found, it is very easy to prove that it is `Omega(2^n)` and also not that hard to prove that it is `BigO(2^n)`.

Any help? thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hint: compare the expanded recurrence relations for `T(n)` and `T(n + 1)` side-by-side - spot anything in common?

Comment: Your recurrence is correct. You've found lower and upper bound - what else do they want?